# How to set up Azure API Management for multi-tenant SaaS environment

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I would like to get expert opinion, if below approach is fine. 
I am creating a SaaS based Multi-tenant solution. There are few APIs, which I want to expose to external world using Azure API management.

- In Azure Portal, we will be creating API (say myAPI) in API management and configure it to our actual web API app.
- Whenever we are adding new Tenant in our Azure SaaS Application, we will be following below steps (using APIs of API management through .net Application):
  -Create Product as the Tenant. e.g. if tenant name is ABC, then we will be creating a Product as "ABC" in Azure API management.
  -Create a Group also with name like "ABC_Group". 
  -Associate user's of Tenant "ABC" to "ABC_Group" and then assign this group to the product "ABC".
  -Associate this product with myAPI.

I would like to get some advice, should we add Tenant name as a Product in API management. So e.g. we will be creating 100 product for 100 Tenant. Or is there any better solution?